# adding line to same power source causes light switch to stay on

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle, light-fixture

New enclosee porch.

I'm installing 2 single pole light switches and an outlet using 12-2.

1. first light switch powers 1 fixtures (den lights)
2. second light switch powers 2 fixtures (exterior wall lights)
3. regular outlet

Only 1 light switch is connected to a fixture (den light) for now. The second switch is pre wiring no fixtures attached yet. the outlet line is also pre wiring.

when split into 3 lines. the second switch stays on. 2 lines works fine.

Please help.

thanks in advance.

attachee is image.[image]

Comment: No white to the outlet? Shouldn't be post 2011, but I wonder if the "input" is a switch loop. What indicates that the second switch is on if no fixtures are attached to it?

Comment: How is the wiring that goes to the outlet connected to the existing switch box wiring?  Can you add a photo looking into back of the switch box?

Comment: it is split into 3 in the wiring box from the power source.

Comment: why did you take only the black wire from the switch box? Why not the white also?

Comment: it is both white and black, i should have drawn in yellow like the other diagram.. but the swigly line near the outlet shows it

Comment: i was able to fix it by changing to another power source on a different circuit breaker. I did this by removing the old power source which is 12-2 20 amp and moving it to a nearby source which is 14-2 15 amp. Since I already ran the 12-2 wires, i just left it but the power source is 14-2. Which is fine as long as it is not the other way around l.